# Deserializing protobufs without source file

Tags: java, ruby, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to deserialize a protobuf message without access to the source .proto file/generated classes? My source system generates messages using Ruby and consumes in Java. The source system can create new message formats that the consumer has no easy way of knowing about. Alternatively, what's the best way for the consumer to get access to the proto classes? Is it possible have some kind of a proto repository?

Comment: What do you expect to do with the proto messages whose meaning you haven't been told?  Are you just passing them along elsewhere?

Comment: Pretty much - either pass them along or persist them somewhere.

Comment: then why do you have to deserialize them at all?  You can always just store the raw bytes.  (Deserializing them will be very hard or impossible, but it's not clear that you actually have to.)

Comment: The idea is to store it in a hive table - all methods seem to require access to the source proto to deserialize.

Comment: I've never encountered Hive, but that still seems odd.  Can you not just store it as an arbitrary byte array?  Or create a dummy proto that just contains an untyped byte array and store it as that?

Comment: I certainly could. But I'd still need the source to read or do anything else with that data.

Comment: it's not clear what you'd expect to be able to do with data whose meaning you haven't been told.  You could send around proto descriptors, which describe a protobuf message format as a proto itself, I suppose.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description might be relevant to your needs?

Comment: The idea is to persist arbitrary data sent as a proto message to some storage system. I'd like to decouple from the source schema and be able to interpret it without access to the source proto file. I have been playing around with the FileDescriptorSet and sending the proto schema as part of the payload. I'm not sure if the ruby gem supports it though.

Comment: Bottomline is that if you don't have source `.proto`, then, you cannot interpret the message in any meaningful way.  What you are left with is a byte array, and you can do with it whatever you could with any other byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the schema (`.proto` file or compiled `Descriptor`), you can only decode a Protobuf into a series of tag/value pairs, where the tags are numeric and the values have limited type information. This may be enough for a human to reverse-engineer the protocol but usually isn't useful for code.

It is possible to send the schema along with the payload by sending along a `FileDescriptorSet` (basically, a compiled version of the relevant `.proto` files), as described here:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description

However, this is not as useful as it sounds! A `FileDescriptorSet` will allow you to determine the names and types of fields, but that doesn't mean your code will know what to do with them.

That said, there are some possible use cases:

- You could have a proxy that translates the message to JSON based on the schema.
- You could have a storage system which parses the message in order to store it in a different form. For example, it might transpose rows and columns for better compression, or it might do some sort of indexing on fields.

However, in these use cases I would generally recommend that the proxy or storage system be pre-configured with the necessary schemas rather than sending them with every message, as schemas tend to be pretty big.